# which dll changes if make changes in contoller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know which `.dll` files will be changed if I'll edit the **HomeController**, for deployment of my project. because i don't want to place my whole bunch of code again. 
I've searched around google but I'm not able to get the exact answer. I checked my `.dll` files but I'm not able to figure out.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Reason for down voting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dll name would be same as your `Project Name`
```

Comment: I've two projects in my solution explorer. One is REST web service and another is MVC4 that is using that rest service. If i made changed in Home controller which dll will change ? can you elaborate your answer ?

Comment: the project in which `homecontroller` exists not the `Rest` service project

Comment: Somehow i came to know that only a single dll changes if you make some changes in code. so i want to know that exact dll.

Comment: That's what i am telling you only one dll is changed project in which controller exists...can you show me your project structure so that i can tell you which dll is changed

Comment: This should be the right answer. To clarify, *solution* is a complete product, it consists from *projects*, when you change source file of the project, only that project will be *recompiled*. So just look to which project `HomeController` belongs -> this will be what you have to redeploy.